# as if in arrest of something

Tags: phrases

In The Fairy Tale of Father Brown by G. K. Chesterton, the author was talking about a prince that went to a very old man to ask him about the place of an old treasure, and when the prince said the word of "gold", the old man held out his hand **as if in arrest of something**, and turned away his face to the mountains.

“‘He has spoken of gold,’ he said. ‘He has spoken of things not lawful. Let him cease to speak.’

Does that mean he held out his hand as he want or arrest or hold sth, or as if his hand was arrested?

Comment: Note that "arrest", in it's most basic meaning, means "stop".  So he held his hand up, likely palm forward, signalling "Stop!"

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks a lot